# How to install rabbitmq server on Windows?

Tags: windows, server, build, rabbitmq, cygwin

How do I install RabbitMQ on Windows?

Comment: You might want to add more details about what you're doing and what you've tried so far.  You have a couple of questions that are extremely similar to each other, and it would help to differentiate them.

Comment: See [this](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-in-dotnet/) tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Installation from a complete bundle

The bundle zip file contains all the files listed in the next section, including an Erlang system installer and the RabbitMQ broker binary distribution, the .Net client, as well as an archive of the Java librabbitmq client library.[http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html]

1. install for windows erlang5.7.4 [otp_win32_R13B03].
2. Download rabbitmq-server-windows-2.0.0.zip from the download page.

3.Contained in the zip file is a directory named rabbitmq_server-2.0.0. You should extract this folder to somewhere appropriate for application files, for example C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ.

4.Once the files are successfully extracted, you should end up with a structure similar to      C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-2.0.0.

5. set the environment variable ERLANG_HOME to point to your Erlang directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\erl5.7.4)

6.by default RABBITMQ_BASE path for windows C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\RabbitMQ. your all requird details information such as log file etc are stored in this dir.

Running the Server as an Application

1.rabbitmq_server-2.0.0\sbin and double-click the rabbitmq-server.bat file.

Running the Server as a Service

1.Log in as an administrator and open a command shell (cmd.exe) in the sbin directory where the broker was installed. Install the service by executing

rabbitmq-service.bat install

2.Ensure that a service with the name RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME now appears in the services control panel (services.msc).

for more details just visit http://www.rabbitmq.com/install.html

Comment: These are installation instructions, not for building (compiling) the native Erlang sources.

Comment: Great response Sam. It helped me loads. I did find however that you needed to run **rabbitmq-service /enable** and **rabbitmq-service /start**. But that could just be me. I also came across this article by Justin Etheredge explaining how to use RabbitMQ and C#. Might help! http://www.codethinked.com/using-rabbitmq-with-c-and-net

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ is designed to be built on a Unix machine (we regularly use various Linux distros and OSX).  The community also tests on FreeBSD.

That said, it's certainly possible to build on Windows, but you need a POSIX-like environment.  The simplest way is by far with cygwin:

- Install the latest Erlang from [here](http://www.erlang.org/download.html),
- Get the Cygwin installer from [here](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe),
- Run it to install the base system; make sure you also have `make`, `libxslt`/`xlstproc` and `mercurial` selected; if you forget anything, you can safely re-run the installer to get the missing programs;
- Update your PATH to include python and erl (so, add something like `C:\Program Files\erl5.8.3\bin` and `C:\Python27\bin`; of course, your paths will probably be different); check that everything works by running `python` and `erl`,
- get the RabbitMQ [source](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server) (you'll also need [the codegen](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-codegen)) via Mercurial;
- from a cygwin shell, run `make` in the `rabbitmq-server` directory.

The last two steps are the normal Unix installation procedure.  See the official [instructions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/build-server.html) for more details.

Also, note that you may have to run the broker (`scripts/rabbitmq-server.bat`) from a normal command prompt and *not* a cygwin shell.  This is due to a discrepancy between what Erlang and Cygwin think the root directory is `/`.

If you have any problems, send a message to the [rabbitmq-discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The developers make a point of answering all queries posted there.

Answer (score 1):

First, download and install **Erlang** for Windows from [**Download Erlang/OTP**](https://www.erlang.org/downloads):

[image]

Then, download and install **RabbitMQ** for Windows from [**Direct Downloads**](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#downloads):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not really much point in doing this unless you intend to develop Erlang code, and in that case you should spend a day or two learning the basics of Erlang. After that it will be less of a struggle because RabbitMQ is written in Erlang.

I have built Erlang on Linux, but on Windows I just installed the binary package because it is just a test/dev environment for me. On Linux I had problems figuring out how to install the binaries and on Windows it took a while to figure out where to put the config file so that I could load plugins.

In any case, you don't run RabbitMQ on Windows or on Linux because it doesn't work that way. Like many Erlang applications, RabbitMQ runs on the cloud (your private cloud) and really expects to be part of a cluster of several servers all running a shared MQ broker service.

Go to this [slide presentation from Google Tech Talks](http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/google-tech-talk-final/google.html) and look at the diagram on slide 17. That is how you would have 4 servers running RabbitMQ in a cluster to serve local clients where local might be one data center out of several in the same geographic region. Local traffic would not cross the cluster but applications don't need to do anything special in order to send/receive messages across the cluster.

Slide 22 sums it up "Making Erlang disappear". You get all the benefits of Erlang without having to learn anything about it. Just use AMQP messaging and many processes. Say goodbye to threads.

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing this. Why do you need a cloud just to run rabbitMQ? I have seen people running rabbitMQ on their LAN and their business processes are running just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Don't bother. Apparently it is "somehow" possible with Cygwin but I gave up too and consequently lost interest. This is a common problem rooted in Erlang culture, which doesn't really seem to understand cross-platform development.

Comment: That's negative and a bit pointless.  The steps on installing with Cygwin aren't that hard, see my answer below.